# Missing cgroup hierarchy in LXC container

Tags: linux, lxc, lxd

Armed with this LXD configuration:

`raw.lxc: |-
  lxc.mount.auto = cgroup:mixed`

A 4.x kernel, and no AppArmor. I should see the cgroup hierarchy in my guest os under `/sys/fs/cgroup` right?  Instead, I see only a guest cgroup folder.

I'm under the impression, because I have a 4.x kernel that I don't need cgmanager / cgproxy installed..

I have tried other things:

- using cgroup (without :mixed)
- `/var/log/messages` and `tail -f /var/log/lxd/mycontainer/* &`
- I'm not running apparmor .. I did try `lxc.aa_profile = unconfined`

In the guest OS, I have only a top-level folder `/sys/fs/cgroup` ..

Comment: Is this a bug or normal?

Answer (score 0):

> stgraberProject leader
>
> If on a kernel which supports cgroup namespacing, liblxc will not mount any cgroups for you, instead letting your init system in the container take care of that.

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-cgroups-will-not-show-up/1148